# MATLAB - Is there a way to do a string compare using multiple strings

Tags: matlab

I have a list of strings that I am looking for in a pdb

```
X1 = ['N' 'CA' 'CB' 'CG1']%Isoleucine
```

I want to compare these strings to the atoms as so:

```
atoms = find(strcmp({pdb.Model.Atom(:).resName}, 'ILE') & ...
               (strcmp({pdb.Model.Atom(:).AtomName}, 'N') |...
                strcmp({pdb.Model.Atom(:).AtomName}, 'CA') | ...
                strcmp({pdb.Model.Atom(:).AtomName}, 'CB') | ...
                strcmp({pdb.Model.Atom(:).AtomName}, 'CG1')))
```

Is there a more concise way to do this? Also is there a way for strcmp to do an exact match? not just if it contains the string?

EDIT:

A more concrete example:

I want to be able to do this:

```
strcmp(['hello' 'world'], ['hello' 'world' 'this' 'is' 'a' 'test'])
```

and it returns whether it matched with hello or world. This instead returns a zero saying that it can't find this array `['hello' 'world']` in `['hello' 'world' 'this' 'is' 'a' 'test']`.

Essentially I just want to know if 'hello' and 'world' are in the larger array instead of checking if it contains both 'hello' and 'world' in the same row

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I have added a more concrete example

Comment: Note that `['hello' 'world']` is not a list of strings in MATLAB: it's a single string `'helloworld'`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks! I did not realize this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first half of your question makes me uncertain, but the second formulation is easily answerable:

```
>> ismember({'hello' 'world'}, {'hello' 'world' 'this' 'is' 'a' 'test'})

ans =

     1     1
```

As you can see, `ismember` works for cell arrays (which is *the* general container for strings). So you can probably use `all` to check the presence of each of the strings in the larger collection:

```
all(ismember({pdb.Model.Atom(:).AtomName},{'N','CA','CB','CG1'}))
```

Comment: And may I also suggest the use of `upper` to convert all your AtomNames to uppercase before you do the comparison for the rainy day when Ca Cb creep into the AtomName